# What Limitation of std::async is Stroustrup Referring To?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, concurrency, language-lawyer

In the “tutorial” chapter 5.3.5.3 of his book *The C++ Programming Language* (4th edition), Bjarne Stroustrup writes about the `std::async` function.

> There is an obvious limitation: Don't even think of using `async()` for tasks that share resources needing locking – with `async()` you don't even know how many `thread`s will be used because that's up to `async()` to decide based on what it knows about the system resources available at the time of a call.

A similar exhortation can be found in [the C++11-FAQ on his website](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-async).

> “Simple” is the most important aspect of the `async()`/`future` design; futures can also be used with threads in general, but don't even *think* of using `async()` to launch tasks that do I/O, manipulates mutexes, or in other ways interact with other tasks.

Interestingly, he doesn't elaborate on this limitation when he returns to C++11's concurrency features in more detail in § 42.4.6 of his book.  Even more interestingly, in this chapter he actually continues (compare to the statement on his website):

> A simple and realistic use of `async()` would be to spawn a task to collect input from a user.

[The documentation of `async` on `cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) does not mention any such limitations at all.

After reading some proposals and discussions that lead to the C++11 standard in its final form (which unfortunately I don't have access to), I understand that `async` was incorporated very late into the C++11 standard and there was a lot of discussion how powerful this feature should be.  In particular, I found the article [*Async Tasks in C++11: Not Quite There Yet* by Bartosz Milewski](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/10/10/async-tasks-in-c11-not-quite-there-yet/) a very good summary of the problems that have to be considered when implementing `async`.

However, all discussed problems are related to `thread_local` variables that are not destructed if a thread is recycled, spurious deadlocks or data access violations if a thread switches its task mid-action and both tasks hold a `mutex` or `recursive_mutex` respectively and so forth.  These are serious concerns for implementors of the feature but if I understand correctly, the current specification of `async` requires all these details be hidden from the user by executing the task either on the caller's thread or *as if* a new thread was created for the task.

So my question is: **What am I not allowed to do with `async` that I am allowed to do using `thread`s manually and what is the reason for this limitation?**

For example, is there anything wrong with the following program?

```c++11
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

static int tally {};
static std::mutex tally_mutex {};

static void
do_work(const int amount)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
    {
      // Might do something actually useful...
      const std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock {tally_mutex};
      tally += 1;
    }
}

int
main()
{
  constexpr int concurrency {10};
  constexpr int amount {1000000};
  std::vector<std::future<void>> futures {};
  for (int t = 0; t < concurrency; ++t)
    futures.push_back(std::async(do_work, amount / concurrency));
  for (auto& future : futures)
    future.get();
  std::cout << tally << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously, if the runtime decides to schedule all tasks on the main thread, we will needlessly acquire the mutex over and over again for no good reason.  But while this might be *inefficient*, it is not *incorrect*.

Comment: As in Stroustrup's example - don't do locks, you can easily get deadlock cause it's not guaranteed that async will be executed in another thread.
In your example, just lock mutex in main function before calling async.

Comment: @DmitriSosnik Can you explain how exactly this could deadlock?  Acquiring the mutex once in the main thread before launching the tasks will certainly not deadlock but also reduce the use of a mutex ad absurdum and give `tally` a garbage value.  Anyway, my question is what are the limitations of `std::async`, not what is the best way to set a variable to 1000000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "problem" with std::async is that by default you don't know whether or not it starts a thread. If your function needs to run on a separate thread then this is a problem as your function might not run until get() or wait() is called.
You can pass std::launch::async to ensure the function is launched on its own thread, which is like a std::thread that cannot BG e detached.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I'll take that answer as “basically, there are no constraints” because to me, that “problem” is actually just the semantics of `std::async` so referring to it as a limitation is somehow like saying “don't use `fread` to write to files”.  Of course, when implementing a producer-consumer pair, it would be a really bad idea to use `std::async` with default launch policy.

Answer (score 0):

You pin pointed the problem.
Threads can be recycled...
So any use of thread_local storage is dangerous.

Your loop is just - but, as you mentioned, might be inefficient.

You can require the language to produce another thread using std::launch::async.
But threads might still be recycled.

Comment: Thank you.  The thing I'm curious about is that – if I understand the standard correctly – the implementation must behave *as if* it had created a new thread (or executed the task directly on the caller's thread), even if it actually recycled one.  So where is the point that is “dangerous” with `std::async` but safe with `std::thread`?  But if you can back up your claim that the construct in my example is standard compliant, I will accept your answer.